# Why do my WDC WD20EARX-00PASB0 in a RAID don't stop spinning?

Tags: hard-drive, filesystem, raid

My disks have been spinning for months. It started with Ubuntu 11.10, and continues with 12.04. I can't figure out how to stop it. I've looked at various folks suggestions online about ext4 commit times, noatime, etc. I've done what they said, but still no luck. It's now like chinese water torture...I hear those disks whir constantly it's starting to drive me insane.

jdb2/dm-1-8 and jbd2/db-0-8 are typically the top IO users. However, I've shut almost everything down, "echo 1 > /proc/sys/vm/block_dump", and watched dmesg. jbd2/dm-1 and jdb2/dm-0 flush reliably every 60 seconds, yet the hard drive continues to spin in the interim. dm-1 is mounted on /home, and dm-0 is mounted as /.

My setup is a bit complicated:

I have a SSD where root lives, and then two regular drives mirrored with software RAID where other LVM paritions live.

On top of this lives LVM partitions. Then, /home is encrypted with ecryptfs.

Here's pvdisplay output:

```
  --- Physical volume ---
  PV Name               /dev/sdd6
  VG Name               ROOT_VG
  PV Size               211.46 GiB / not usable 4.00 MiB
  Allocatable           yes 
  PE Size               4.00 MiB
  Total PE              54134
  Free PE               18372
  Allocated PE          35762
  PV UUID               1aqBph-m45Y-0bs5-FU7t-zmR7-slLE-ItLneR
```

--- Physical volume ---
  PV Name               /dev/md2
  VG Name               FF_VG
  PV Size               1.82 TiB / not usable 2.87 MiB
  Allocatable           yes 
  PE Size               4.00 MiB
  Total PE              476931
  Free PE               158882
  Allocated PE          318049
  PV UUID               Em7a94-ijwz-YdmO-dBCi-e3N6-EzaA-hX50vJ

Here's the definition and state of that raid partition:

```
/dev/md2:
        Version : 1.2
  Creation Time : Thu Jan 12 05:57:20 2012
     Raid Level : raid1
     Array Size : 1953512312 (1863.01 GiB 2000.40 GB)
  Used Dev Size : 1953512312 (1863.01 GiB 2000.40 GB)
   Raid Devices : 2
  Total Devices : 2
    Persistence : Superblock is persistent
```

```
Update Time : Fri Apr 20 09:11:18 2012
      State : clean
```

Active Devices : 2
Working Devices : 2
 Failed Devices : 0
  Spare Devices : 0

```
       Name : mymachine:2  (local to host mymachine)
       UUID : d2d341dc:e3a8c880:3856e567:02f6ab33
     Events : 124244

Number   Major   Minor   RaidDevice State
   3       8        1        0      active sync   /dev/sda1
   2       8       33        1      active sync   /dev/sdc1
```

And here's lvdisplay output:

--- Logical volume ---
  LV Name                /dev/ROOT_VG/ROOT_LV
  VG Name                ROOT_VG
  LV UUID                GpQjds-24TR-wO9O-sfdx-7IWc-2O5P-goEW05
  LV Write Access        read/write
  LV Status              available
  # open                 1
  LV Size                139.70 GiB
  Current LE             35762
  Segments               1
  Allocation             inherit
  Read ahead sectors     auto
  - currently set to     256
  Block device           252:0

--- Logical volume ---
  LV Name                /dev/FF_VG/HOME_LV
  VG Name                FF_VG
  LV UUID                6aZo1j-S55P-werD-xMmz-JopL-dkjd-cAHgdR
  LV Write Access        read/write
  LV Status              available
  # open                 1
  LV Size                698.49 GiB
  Current LE             178814
  Segments               1
  Allocation             inherit
  Read ahead sectors     auto
  - currently set to     256
  Block device           252:1

--- Logical volume ---
  LV Name                /dev/FF_VG/SWAP_LV
  VG Name                FF_VG
  LV UUID                Ea5Epe-IXCH-Zgr7-dMaL-UCZi-5nsW-SN6GSZ
  LV Write Access        read/write
  LV Status              available
  # open                 2
  LV Size                22.35 GiB
  Current LE             5722
  Segments               1
  Allocation             inherit
  Read ahead sectors     auto
  - currently set to     256
  Block device           252:2

--- Logical volume ---
  LV Name                /dev/FF_VG/OPT_LV
  VG Name                FF_VG
  LV UUID                buGIdk-pdtG-msUd-1gVn-DECF-qzZR-2oMqRT
  LV Write Access        read/write
  LV Status              available
  # open                 1
  LV Size                139.70 GiB
  Current LE             35762
  Segments               1
  Allocation             inherit
  Read ahead sectors     auto
  - currently set to     256
  Block device           252:3

--- Logical volume ---
  LV Name                /dev/FF_VG/VMS_LV
  VG Name                FF_VG
  LV UUID                AJkQgB-L0pp-Y3Tk-Rs9e-P4ox-XI0n-1TCxbH
  LV Write Access        read/write
  LV Status              available
  # open                 1
  LV Size                102.45 GiB
  Current LE             26226
  Segments               1
  Allocation             inherit
  Read ahead sectors     auto
  - currently set to     256
  Block device           252:4

--- Logical volume ---
  LV Name                /dev/FF_VG/DATA_LV
  VG Name                FF_VG
  LV UUID                4g38kT-ggv8-b12C-WPxF-buhB-zxtj-MGl0TX
  LV Write Access        read/write
  LV Status              available
  # open                 1
  LV Size                279.39 GiB
  Current LE             71525
  Segments               1
  Allocation             inherit
  Read ahead sectors     auto
  - currently set to     256
  Block device           252:5

Here's mtab:

```
/dev/mapper/ROOT_VG-ROOT_LV / ext4 rw,commit=60,errors=remount-ro 0 0
proc /proc proc rw,noexec,nosuid,nodev 0 0
sysfs /sys sysfs rw,noexec,nosuid,nodev 0 0
none /sys/fs/fuse/connections fusectl rw 0 0
none /sys/kernel/debug debugfs rw 0 0
none /sys/kernel/security securityfs rw 0 0
udev /dev devtmpfs rw,mode=0755 0 0
devpts /dev/pts devpts rw,noexec,nosuid,gid=5,mode=0620 0 0
tmpfs /run tmpfs rw,noexec,nosuid,size=10%,mode=0755 0 0
none /run/lock tmpfs rw,noexec,nosuid,nodev,size=5242880 0 0
none /run/shm tmpfs rw,nosuid,nodev 0 0
/dev/sdd1 /boot ext2 rw 0 0
/dev/mapper/FF_VG-HOME_LV /home ext4 rw,noatime,commit=60 0 0
/dev/mapper/FF_VG-DATA_LV /data ext4 rw,noatime,commit=60 0 0
/dev/mapper/FF_VG-VMS_LV /vms ext4 rw,noatime,commit=60 0 0
/dev/mapper/FF_VG-OPT_LV /opt ext4 rw,noatime,commit=60 0 0
binfmt_misc /proc/sys/fs/binfmt_misc binfmt_misc rw,noexec,nosuid,nodev 0 0
/home/myuser/.Private /home/myuser ecryptfs ecryptfs_check_dev_ruid,ecryptfs_cipher=aes,ecryptfs_key_bytes=16,ecryptfs_unlink_sigs,ecryptfs_sig=9823493038bb4fe3,ecryptfs_fnek_sig=5687e349843fce9cb 0 0
gvfs-fuse-daemon /home/myuser/.gvfs fuse.gvfs-fuse-daemon rw,nosuid,nodev,user=myuser 0 0
```

Here's hdparm -I on each device:

########### /dev/sdd

/dev/sdd:

ATA device, with non-removable media
    Model Number:       M4-CT256M4SSD2
    Serial Number:      xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx
    Firmware Revision:  0009
    Transport:          Serial, ATA8-AST, SATA 1.0a, SATA II Extensions, SATA Rev 2.5, SATA Rev 2.6, SATA Rev 3.0
Standards:
    Used: unknown (minor revision code 0x0028) 
    Supported: 9 8 7 6 5 
    Likely used: 9
Configuration:
    Logical     max current
    cylinders   16383   16383
    heads       16  16
    sectors/track   63  63
    --
    CHS current addressable sectors:   16514064
    LBA    user addressable sectors:  268435455
    LBA48  user addressable sectors:  500118192
    Logical  Sector size:                   512 bytes
    Physical Sector size:                   512 bytes
    Logical Sector-0 offset:                  0 bytes
    device size with M = 1024*1024:      244198 MBytes
    device size with M = 1000*1000:      256060 MBytes (256 GB)
    cache/buffer size  = unknown
    Form Factor: 2.5 inch
    Nominal Media Rotation Rate: Solid State Device
Capabilities:
    LBA, IORDY(can be disabled)
    Queue depth: 32
    Standby timer values: spec'd by Standard, with device specific minimum
    R/W multiple sector transfer: Max = 16  Current = 16
    Advanced power management level: 254
    DMA: mdma0 mdma1 mdma2 udma0 udma1 udma2 udma3 udma4 *udma5 
         Cycle time: min=120ns recommended=120ns
    PIO: pio0 pio1 pio2 pio3 pio4 
         Cycle time: no flow control=120ns  IORDY flow control=120ns
Commands/features:
    Enabled Supported:
       *    SMART feature set
            Security Mode feature set
       *    Power Management feature set
       *    Write cache
       *    Look-ahead
       *    Host Protected Area feature set
       *    WRITE_BUFFER command
       *    READ_BUFFER command
       *    NOP cmd
       *    DOWNLOAD_MICROCODE
       *    Advanced Power Management feature set
            SET_MAX security extension
       *    48-bit Address feature set
       *    Device Configuration Overlay feature set
       *    Mandatory FLUSH_CACHE
       *    FLUSH_CACHE_EXT
       *    SMART error logging
       *    SMART self-test
       *    General Purpose Logging feature set
       *    WRITE_{DMA|MULTIPLE}_FUA_EXT
       *    64-bit World wide name
       *    IDLE_IMMEDIATE with UNLOAD
            Write-Read-Verify feature set
       *    WRITE_UNCORRECTABLE_EXT command
       *    {READ,WRITE}_DMA_EXT_GPL commands
       *    Segmented DOWNLOAD_MICROCODE
       *    Gen1 signaling speed (1.5Gb/s)
       *    Gen2 signaling speed (3.0Gb/s)
       *    Gen3 signaling speed (6.0Gb/s)
       *    Native Command Queueing (NCQ)
       *    Host-initiated interface power management
       *    Phy event counters
       *    NCQ priority information
            DMA Setup Auto-Activate optimization
            Device-initiated interface power management
       *    Software settings preservation
       *    SMART Command Transport (SCT) feature set
       *    SCT LBA Segment Access (AC2)
       *    SCT Error Recovery Control (AC3)
       *    SCT Features Control (AC4)
       *    SCT Data Tables (AC5)
       *    Data Set Management TRIM supported (limit 8 blocks)
       *    Deterministic read data after TRIM
Security: 
    Master password revision code = xxxxx
        supported
    not enabled
    not locked
    not frozen
    not expired: security count
        supported: enhanced erase
    2min for SECURITY ERASE UNIT. 2min for ENHANCED SECURITY ERASE UNIT.
Logical Unit WWN Device Identifier: xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx
    NAA     : 5
    IEEE OUI    : xxxxx
    Unique ID   : xxxxxxxx

################### /dev/sda

/dev/sda:

ATA device, with non-removable media
    Model Number:       WDC WD20EARX-00PASB0
    Serial Number:      xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx
    Firmware Revision:  51.0AB51
    Transport:          Serial, SATA 1.0a, SATA II Extensions, SATA Rev 2.5, SATA Rev 2.6, SATA Rev 3.0
Standards:
    Supported: 8 7 6 5 
    Likely used: 8
Configuration:
    Logical     max current
    cylinders   16383   16383
    heads       16  16
    sectors/track   63  63
    --
    CHS current addressable sectors:   16514064
    LBA    user addressable sectors:  268435455
    LBA48  user addressable sectors: 3907029168
    Logical  Sector size:                   512 bytes
    Physical Sector size:                  4096 bytes
    Logical Sector-0 offset:                  0 bytes
    device size with M = 1024*1024:     1907729 MBytes
    device size with M = 1000*1000:     2000398 MBytes (2000 GB)
    cache/buffer size  = unknown
Capabilities:
    LBA, IORDY(can be disabled)
    Queue depth: 32
    Standby timer values: spec'd by Standard, with device specific minimum
    R/W multiple sector transfer: Max = 16  Current = 0
    DMA: mdma0 mdma1 mdma2 udma0 udma1 udma2 udma3 udma4 udma5 *udma6 
         Cycle time: min=120ns recommended=120ns
    PIO: pio0 pio1 pio2 pio3 pio4 
         Cycle time: no flow control=120ns  IORDY flow control=120ns
Commands/features:
    Enabled Supported:
       *    SMART feature set
            Security Mode feature set
       *    Power Management feature set
       *    Write cache
       *    Look-ahead
       *    Host Protected Area feature set
       *    WRITE_BUFFER command
       *    READ_BUFFER command
       *    NOP cmd
       *    DOWNLOAD_MICROCODE
            Power-Up In Standby feature set
       *    SET_FEATURES required to spinup after power up
            SET_MAX security extension
       *    48-bit Address feature set
       *    Device Configuration Overlay feature set
       *    Mandatory FLUSH_CACHE
       *    FLUSH_CACHE_EXT
       *    SMART error logging
       *    SMART self-test
       *    General Purpose Logging feature set
       *    64-bit World wide name
       *    WRITE_UNCORRECTABLE_EXT command
       *    {READ,WRITE}_DMA_EXT_GPL commands
       *    Segmented DOWNLOAD_MICROCODE
       *    Gen1 signaling speed (1.5Gb/s)
       *    Gen2 signaling speed (3.0Gb/s)
       *    Gen3 signaling speed (6.0Gb/s)
       *    Native Command Queueing (NCQ)
       *    Host-initiated interface power management
       *    Phy event counters
       *    NCQ priority information
            DMA Setup Auto-Activate optimization
       *    Software settings preservation
       *    SMART Command Transport (SCT) feature set
       *    SCT LBA Segment Access (AC2)
       *    SCT Features Control (AC4)
       *    SCT Data Tables (AC5)
            unknown 206[12] (vendor specific)
            unknown 206[13] (vendor specific)
Security: 
    Master password revision code = xxxxx
        supported
    not enabled
    not locked
    not frozen
    not expired: security count
        supported: enhanced erase
    396min for SECURITY ERASE UNIT. 396min for ENHANCED SECURITY ERASE UNIT.
Logical Unit WWN Device Identifier: xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx
    NAA     : x
    IEEE OUI    : xxxxxx
    Unique ID   : xxxxxxxx
Checksum: correct

################### /dev/sdc

/dev/sdc:

ATA device, with non-removable media
    Model Number:       WDC WD20EARX-00PASB0
    Serial Number:      xxxxxxxxx
    Firmware Revision:  51.0AB51
    Transport:          Serial, SATA 1.0a, SATA II Extensions, SATA Rev 2.5, SATA Rev 2.6, SATA Rev 3.0
Standards:
    Supported: 8 7 6 5 
    Likely used: 8
Configuration:
    Logical     max current
    cylinders   16383   16383
    heads       16  16
    sectors/track   63  63
    --
    CHS current addressable sectors:   16514064
    LBA    user addressable sectors:  268435455
    LBA48  user addressable sectors: 3907029168
    Logical  Sector size:                   512 bytes
    Physical Sector size:                  4096 bytes
    Logical Sector-0 offset:                  0 bytes
    device size with M = 1024*1024:     1907729 MBytes
    device size with M = 1000*1000:     2000398 MBytes (2000 GB)
    cache/buffer size  = unknown
Capabilities:
    LBA, IORDY(can be disabled)
    Queue depth: 32
    Standby timer values: spec'd by Standard, with device specific minimum
    R/W multiple sector transfer: Max = 16  Current = 0
    DMA: mdma0 mdma1 mdma2 udma0 udma1 udma2 udma3 udma4 udma5 *udma6 
         Cycle time: min=120ns recommended=120ns
    PIO: pio0 pio1 pio2 pio3 pio4 
         Cycle time: no flow control=120ns  IORDY flow control=120ns
Commands/features:
    Enabled Supported:
       *    SMART feature set
            Security Mode feature set
       *    Power Management feature set
       *    Write cache
       *    Look-ahead
       *    Host Protected Area feature set
       *    WRITE_BUFFER command
       *    READ_BUFFER command
       *    NOP cmd
       *    DOWNLOAD_MICROCODE
            Power-Up In Standby feature set
       *    SET_FEATURES required to spinup after power up
            SET_MAX security extension
       *    48-bit Address feature set
       *    Device Configuration Overlay feature set
       *    Mandatory FLUSH_CACHE
       *    FLUSH_CACHE_EXT
       *    SMART error logging
       *    SMART self-test
       *    General Purpose Logging feature set
       *    64-bit World wide name
       *    WRITE_UNCORRECTABLE_EXT command
       *    {READ,WRITE}_DMA_EXT_GPL commands
       *    Segmented DOWNLOAD_MICROCODE
       *    Gen1 signaling speed (1.5Gb/s)
       *    Gen2 signaling speed (3.0Gb/s)
       *    Gen3 signaling speed (6.0Gb/s)
       *    Native Command Queueing (NCQ)
       *    Host-initiated interface power management
       *    Phy event counters
       *    NCQ priority information
            DMA Setup Auto-Activate optimization
       *    Software settings preservation
       *    SMART Command Transport (SCT) feature set
       *    SCT LBA Segment Access (AC2)
       *    SCT Features Control (AC4)
       *    SCT Data Tables (AC5)
            unknown 206[12] (vendor specific)
            unknown 206[13] (vendor specific)
Security: 
    Master password revision code = xxxxx
        supported
    not enabled
    not locked
    not frozen
    not expired: security count
        supported: enhanced erase
    388min for SECURITY ERASE UNIT. 388min for ENHANCED SECURITY ERASE UNIT.
Logical Unit WWN Device Identifier: xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx
    NAA     : x
    IEEE OUI    : xxxxxx
    Unique ID   : xxxxxxxxx
Checksum: correct
 
After shutting most things down, including rsyslogd, and running iotop for a few minutes, there are the top talkers. Notice how little I/O is going on, yet the disks keep spinning:

```
Total DISK READ:       0.00 B/s | Total DISK WRITE:       0.00 B/s
  TID  PRIO  USER     DISK READ  DISK WRITE  SWAPIN     IO>    COMMAND

 1207 be/3 root          0.00 B     24.00 K  0.00 %  0.02 % [jbd2/dm-1-8]
  436 be/3 root          0.00 B     20.00 K  0.00 %  0.00 % [jbd2/dm-0-8]
    1 be/4 root          0.00 B      0.00 B  0.00 %  0.00 % init
    2 be/4 root          0.00 B      0.00 B  0.00 %  0.00 % [kthreadd]
    3 be/4 root          0.00 B      0.00 B  0.00 %  0.00 % [ksoftirqd/0]
    6 rt/4 root          0.00 B      0.00 B  0.00 %  0.00 % [migration/0]
    7 rt/4 root          0.00 B      0.00 B  0.00 %  0.00 % [watchdog/0]
    8 rt/4 root          0.00 B      0.00 B  0.00 %  0.00 % [migration/1]
   10 be/4 root          0.00 B      0.00 B  0.00 %  0.00 % [ksoftirqd/1]
   12 rt/4 root          0.00 B      0.00 B  0.00 %  0.00 % [watchdog/1]
   13 rt/4 root          0.00 B      0.00 B  0.00 %  0.00 % [migration/2]
   14 be/4 root          0.00 B      0.00 B  0.00 %  0.00 % [kworker/2:0]
   15 be/4 root          0.00 B      0.00 B  0.00 %  0.00 % [ksoftirqd/2]
   16 rt/4 root          0.00 B      0.00 B  0.00 %  0.00 % [watchdog/2]
   17 rt/4 root          0.00 B      0.00 B  0.00 %  0.00 % [migration/3]
   19 be/4 root          0.00 B      0.00 B  0.00 %  0.00 % [ksoftirqd/3]
   20 rt/4 root          0.00 B      0.00 B  0.00 %  0.00 % [watchdog/3]
   21 rt/4 root          0.00 B      0.00 B  0.00 %  0.00 % [migration/4]
   22 be/4 root          0.00 B      0.00 B  0.00 %  0.00 % [kworker/4:0]
   23 be/4 root          0.00 B      0.00 B  0.00 %  0.00 % [ksoftirqd/4]
   24 rt/4 root          0.00 B      0.00 B  0.00 %  0.00 % [watchdog/4]
   25 rt/4 root          0.00 B      0.00 B  0.00 %  0.00 % [migration/5]
```

And finally, here's block_dump output. This is for a two minute period (roughly)...there were pauses when nothing was going on, yet the disks still spin:

```
[74559.007437] flush-252:0(1233): WRITE block 54790360 on dm-0 (8 sectors)
[74562.199606] console-kit-dae(1953): dirtied inode 1573426 (history) on dm-0
[74562.199616] console-kit-dae(1953): dirtied inode 1573426 (history) on dm-0
[74562.199620] console-kit-dae(1953): dirtied inode 1573426 (history) on dm-0
[74562.898697] dmesg(13435): dirtied inode 326099 (out) on tmpfs
[74568.992176] flush-252:0(1233): WRITE block 50331928 on dm-0 (8 sectors)
[74568.992192] flush-252:0(1233): WRITE block 50331936 on dm-0 (8 sectors)
[74568.992200] flush-252:0(1233): WRITE block 50332016 on dm-0 (8 sectors)
[74568.992208] flush-252:0(1233): WRITE block 54525968 on dm-0 (8 sectors)
[74568.992215] flush-252:0(1233): WRITE block 54526080 on dm-0 (8 sectors)
[74568.992222] flush-252:0(1233): WRITE block 54527088 on dm-0 (8 sectors)
[74568.992228] flush-252:0(1233): WRITE block 54593984 on dm-0 (8 sectors)
[74568.992234] flush-252:0(1233): WRITE block 83886088 on dm-0 (8 sectors)
[74568.992240] flush-252:0(1233): WRITE block 83886336 on dm-0 (8 sectors)
[74568.992247] flush-252:0(1233): WRITE block 159385288 on dm-0 (8 sectors)
[74568.992260] flush-252:0(1233): WRITE block 159386960 on dm-0 (8 sectors)
[74568.992266] flush-252:0(1233): WRITE block 192937992 on dm-0 (8 sectors)
[74568.992273] flush-252:0(1233): WRITE block 213910472 on dm-0 (8 sectors)
[74568.992279] flush-252:0(1233): WRITE block 213910720 on dm-0 (8 sectors)
[74568.992285] flush-252:0(1233): WRITE block 213910728 on dm-0 (8 sectors)
[74568.992291] flush-252:0(1233): WRITE block 213910736 on dm-0 (8 sectors)
[74568.992296] flush-252:0(1233): WRITE block 213910744 on dm-0 (8 sectors)
[74568.992301] flush-252:0(1233): WRITE block 213910752 on dm-0 (8 sectors)
[74568.992306] flush-252:0(1233): WRITE block 213910760 on dm-0 (8 sectors)
[74568.992311] flush-252:0(1233): WRITE block 213910768 on dm-0 (8 sectors)
[74568.992316] flush-252:0(1233): WRITE block 213910776 on dm-0 (8 sectors)
[74568.992322] flush-252:0(1233): WRITE block 213911184 on dm-0 (8 sectors)
[74568.992329] flush-252:0(1233): WRITE block 213911192 on dm-0 (8 sectors)
[74568.992335] flush-252:0(1233): WRITE block 213911200 on dm-0 (8 sectors)
[74568.992342] flush-252:0(1233): WRITE block 213911208 on dm-0 (8 sectors)
[74568.992347] flush-252:0(1233): WRITE block 213911216 on dm-0 (8 sectors)
[74568.992353] flush-252:0(1233): WRITE block 213911224 on dm-0 (8 sectors)
[74568.992358] flush-252:0(1233): WRITE block 213912152 on dm-0 (8 sectors)
[74568.992364] flush-252:0(1233): WRITE block 213912256 on dm-0 (8 sectors)
[74568.992371] flush-252:0(1233): WRITE block 213912352 on dm-0 (8 sectors)
[74568.992474] flush-252:0(1233): WRITE block 213912360 on dm-0 (8 sectors)
[74568.992480] flush-252:0(1233): WRITE block 213912440 on dm-0 (8 sectors)
[74568.992486] flush-252:0(1233): WRITE block 213912448 on dm-0 (8 sectors)
[74568.992491] flush-252:0(1233): WRITE block 213912456 on dm-0 (8 sectors)
[74568.992496] flush-252:0(1233): WRITE block 213912472 on dm-0 (8 sectors)
[74568.992502] flush-252:0(1233): WRITE block 213912480 on dm-0 (8 sectors)
[74568.992507] flush-252:0(1233): WRITE block 213912504 on dm-0 (8 sectors)
[74568.992513] flush-252:0(1233): WRITE block 213912536 on dm-0 (8 sectors)
[74568.992521] flush-252:0(1233): WRITE block 213912544 on dm-0 (8 sectors)
[74568.992526] flush-252:0(1233): WRITE block 213912552 on dm-0 (8 sectors)
[74568.992531] flush-252:0(1233): WRITE block 213912560 on dm-0 (8 sectors)
[74568.992536] flush-252:0(1233): WRITE block 213912568 on dm-0 (8 sectors)
[74568.992541] flush-252:0(1233): WRITE block 213912576 on dm-0 (8 sectors)
[74568.992546] flush-252:0(1233): WRITE block 213912584 on dm-0 (8 sectors)
[74568.992552] flush-252:0(1233): WRITE block 213912592 on dm-0 (8 sectors)
[74568.992557] flush-252:0(1233): WRITE block 213912600 on dm-0 (8 sectors)
[74568.992563] flush-252:0(1233): WRITE block 213912608 on dm-0 (8 sectors)
[74568.992568] flush-252:0(1233): WRITE block 213912616 on dm-0 (8 sectors)
[74568.992573] flush-252:0(1233): WRITE block 213912624 on dm-0 (8 sectors)
[74568.992578] flush-252:0(1233): WRITE block 213912632 on dm-0 (8 sectors)
[74568.992583] flush-252:0(1233): WRITE block 213912640 on dm-0 (8 sectors)
[74568.992589] flush-252:0(1233): WRITE block 213912648 on dm-0 (8 sectors)
[74568.992595] flush-252:0(1233): WRITE block 213912656 on dm-0 (8 sectors)
[74568.992600] flush-252:0(1233): WRITE block 213912664 on dm-0 (8 sectors)
[74568.992605] flush-252:0(1233): WRITE block 213912672 on dm-0 (8 sectors)
[74568.992610] flush-252:0(1233): WRITE block 213912680 on dm-0 (8 sectors)
[74568.992615] flush-252:0(1233): WRITE block 213912688 on dm-0 (8 sectors)
[74568.992620] flush-252:0(1233): WRITE block 213912696 on dm-0 (8 sectors)
[74568.992625] flush-252:0(1233): WRITE block 213912704 on dm-0 (8 sectors)
[74568.992631] flush-252:0(1233): WRITE block 213912776 on dm-0 (8 sectors)
[74568.992636] flush-252:0(1233): WRITE block 213912784 on dm-0 (8 sectors)
[74568.992641] flush-252:0(1233): WRITE block 213912792 on dm-0 (8 sectors)
[74568.992646] flush-252:0(1233): WRITE block 213912800 on dm-0 (8 sectors)
[74568.992652] flush-252:0(1233): WRITE block 213912808 on dm-0 (8 sectors)
[74568.992657] flush-252:0(1233): WRITE block 213912816 on dm-0 (8 sectors)
[74568.992695] flush-252:0(1233): WRITE block 213912824 on dm-0 (8 sectors)
[74568.992701] flush-252:0(1233): WRITE block 213912832 on dm-0 (8 sectors)
[74568.992706] flush-252:0(1233): WRITE block 213912840 on dm-0 (8 sectors)
[74568.992711] flush-252:0(1233): WRITE block 213912848 on dm-0 (8 sectors)
[74568.992716] flush-252:0(1233): WRITE block 213912856 on dm-0 (8 sectors)
[74568.992721] flush-252:0(1233): WRITE block 213912864 on dm-0 (8 sectors)
[74568.992726] flush-252:0(1233): WRITE block 213912872 on dm-0 (8 sectors)
[74568.992731] flush-252:0(1233): WRITE block 213912880 on dm-0 (8 sectors)
[74568.992736] flush-252:0(1233): WRITE block 213912888 on dm-0 (8 sectors)
[74568.992742] flush-252:0(1233): WRITE block 213912896 on dm-0 (8 sectors)
[74568.992747] flush-252:0(1233): WRITE block 213912904 on dm-0 (8 sectors)
[74568.992752] flush-252:0(1233): WRITE block 213912912 on dm-0 (8 sectors)
[74568.992757] flush-252:0(1233): WRITE block 213912920 on dm-0 (8 sectors)
[74568.992761] flush-252:0(1233): WRITE block 213912928 on dm-0 (8 sectors)
[74568.992766] flush-252:0(1233): WRITE block 213912936 on dm-0 (8 sectors)
[74568.992776] flush-252:0(1233): WRITE block 213912944 on dm-0 (8 sectors)
[74568.992781] flush-252:0(1233): WRITE block 213912952 on dm-0 (8 sectors)
[74568.992786] flush-252:0(1233): WRITE block 213912960 on dm-0 (8 sectors)
[74568.992791] flush-252:0(1233): WRITE block 276825680 on dm-0 (8 sectors)
[74568.992803] flush-252:0(1233): WRITE block 0 on dm-0 (8 sectors)
[74568.992809] flush-252:0(1233): WRITE block 8 on dm-0 (8 sectors)
[74568.992815] flush-252:0(1233): WRITE block 24 on dm-0 (8 sectors)
[74568.992821] flush-252:0(1233): WRITE block 48 on dm-0 (8 sectors)
[74568.992827] flush-252:0(1233): WRITE block 8388736 on dm-0 (8 sectors)
[74568.992833] flush-252:0(1233): WRITE block 8388864 on dm-0 (8 sectors)
[74568.992840] flush-252:0(1233): WRITE block 8454400 on dm-0 (8 sectors)
[74583.761611] jbd2/dm-1-8(1207): WRITE block 730185808 on dm-1 (8 sectors)
[74583.761703] md2_raid1(381): WRITE block 8 on sdc1 (2 sectors)
[74583.761742] md2_raid1(381): WRITE block 8 on sda1 (2 sectors)
[74584.205263] jbd2/dm-1-8(1207): WRITE block 730185816 on dm-1 (8 sectors)
[74584.205607] jbd2/dm-1-8(1207): WRITE block 730185824 on dm-1 (8 sectors)
[74584.440542] md2_raid1(381): WRITE block 8 on sdc1 (2 sectors)
[74584.440561] md2_raid1(381): WRITE block 8 on sda1 (2 sectors)
[74593.954005] flush-252:0(1233): WRITE block 55173288 on dm-0 (8 sectors)
[74595.844921] console-kit-dae(1953): dirtied inode 1573426 (history) on dm-0
[74595.844932] console-kit-dae(1953): dirtied inode 1573426 (history) on dm-0
[74595.844936] console-kit-dae(1953): dirtied inode 1573426 (history) on dm-0
[74606.894208] jbd2/dm-0-8(436): WRITE block 55173288 on dm-0 (8 sectors)
[74606.894300] jbd2/dm-0-8(436): WRITE block 143068696 on dm-0 (8 sectors)
[74606.894347] jbd2/dm-0-8(436): WRITE block 143068704 on dm-0 (8 sectors)
[74606.894353] jbd2/dm-0-8(436): WRITE block 143068712 on dm-0 (8 sectors)
[74606.894358] jbd2/dm-0-8(436): WRITE block 143068720 on dm-0 (8 sectors)
[74606.894363] jbd2/dm-0-8(436): WRITE block 143068728 on dm-0 (8 sectors)
[74606.894368] jbd2/dm-0-8(436): WRITE block 143068736 on dm-0 (8 sectors)
[74606.894372] jbd2/dm-0-8(436): WRITE block 143068744 on dm-0 (8 sectors)
[74606.894376] jbd2/dm-0-8(436): WRITE block 143068752 on dm-0 (8 sectors)
[74606.894644] jbd2/dm-0-8(436): WRITE block 143068760 on dm-0 (8 sectors)
[74614.202984] flush-252:1(1234): WRITE block 461373696 on dm-1 (8 sectors)
[74614.203067] md2_raid1(381): WRITE block 8 on sdc1 (2 sectors)
[74614.203106] md2_raid1(381): WRITE block 8 on sda1 (2 sectors)
[74614.826060] md2_raid1(381): WRITE block 8 on sdc1 (2 sectors)
[74614.826081] md2_raid1(381): WRITE block 8 on sda1 (2 sectors)
[74640.778344] flush-252:0(1233): WRITE block 50331656 on dm-0 (8 sectors)
[74640.778364] flush-252:0(1233): WRITE block 50332184 on dm-0 (8 sectors)
[74640.778372] flush-252:0(1233): WRITE block 50332640 on dm-0 (8 sectors)
[74640.778379] flush-252:0(1233): WRITE block 50600112 on dm-0 (8 sectors)
[74640.778385] flush-252:0(1233): WRITE block 54525960 on dm-0 (8 sectors)
[74640.778391] flush-252:0(1233): WRITE block 54526440 on dm-0 (8 sectors)
[74640.778402] flush-252:0(1233): WRITE block 16 on dm-0 (8 sectors)
[74745.127994] udev-acl.ck(13987): dirtied inode 327956 (database) on tmpfs
[74745.131156] console-kit-dae(1953): dirtied inode 1573426 (history) on dm-0
[74745.131166] console-kit-dae(1953): dirtied inode 1573426 (history) on dm-0
[74745.131170] console-kit-dae(1953): dirtied inode 1573426 (history) on dm-0
```

Thank you so much for taking a look.

Answer (score 3):

Based on their model numbers (WDC WD20EARX-00PASB0), both of your RAID disks are "Green" drives these are notorious for constantly parking and unparking the drive heads and are not recommended for use for RAID applications.

Take a look at the output of smartctl or via the graphical "Disk Utility" to see the SMART statistics for these drives. They are prone to very high Load/Unload Cycle Counts which results from their power-saving features.

WD provides a utility called "WDIDLE":

http://support.wdc.com/product/download.asp?groupid=609&sid=113

which will allow you to change this property and reduce or disable automatic head parking to help you regain your sanity.

Unfortunately, as mentioned above, these drives are not recommended for use in RAID applications so the best approach would be to replace them with suitable drives and avoid them in future.

Google around for "green drive raid" and you will find lots of people having issues with these drives.

Comment: Thanks Steve. I'll try the utility Monday. If that doesn't work, I'm willing to order new drives. Any recommendation for a raid setup which won't break the bank?

Comment: You're welcome. I have a 1TB WD Green drive and the Load/Uload cycle count was over 900,000 - the drive is rated at only 300,000. This was a result of about a year of light use in a single drive configuration. Check to see what the load counts are to see if these drives will still be within the manufacture's value - I'm not sure what happens when you exceed this number. As far as what drives to use I think the best advice is to stay away from the green models. Find something at a good price then casually research the model to see if anyone has had issues with it.

Comment: So I ordered two new "black" drives, and funny enough, as soon as I removed two older drives which weren't even being mounted by the OS to put these new "black" drives in, the whirring stopped. Both green drives are still in a raid config, but no whirring. I'm baffled.

Comment: How does this work? Why is "discs spinning up/down" resulting in device-flush commands in kernel logs? What is keeping the discs spun up? Why does this register as IO in JBD2 ?  Why am I having this behaviour on a Hitachi? ( No  increments in Load/unload counts for me while this is happening )